# Use if, else in function in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use the below query,but throws an error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerPaymentFunc (@customerCode bigint ) 
RETURNS bigint AS BEGIN
    RETURN 
    ( if(select coun from getCustomerPaymentCount (@customerCode))=0)
     select 0 as price      
      else          
        (select SUM(price) as code 
         from PaymentLog 
         where customerCode=@customerCode)
    ) END
```

I Use below Two but says:

select statement included within a function cannot return data to client

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerPaymentFunc (@customerCode bigint ) 
RETURNS bigint AS BEGIN
RETURN 
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN (select coun from getCustomerPaymentCount(@customerCode))=0      
     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as
 (select SUM(price) as code from PaymentLog 
  where customerCode=@customerCode)
     ) END
```

Comment: Error you say, my young Padawan?

Comment: There is so much syntactical errors in you code that disallows to understand your intention. Can you explain in human language (not in SQL) your intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your intention is to have the function return the sum of price in the `PaymentLog` table for a given `customerCode`, or return 0 if the `customerCode` doesn't exist. If this is correct you could do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerPaymentFunc (@customerCode bigint) RETURNS bigint AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result bigint
    SET @result= (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(price), 0) FROM PaymentLog WHERE customerCode = @customerCode)
    RETURN @result
END
```

If the`customerCode`doesn't exist in the`PaymentLog`table the`SUM()`function will return`NULL`and you can use either the`COALESCE`or the`ISNULL`function to replace the `NULL`value with `0`.

See MSDN: [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)